# LLVM: how to pass a name to ConstantInt

Tags: llvm

Using LLVM's C++ API, I'm calling constantInt->setName("name") but on constantInt->getName() it doesn't show up. I always get the empty string. Is ConstantInt not supposed to have a name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign names to constants (and neither can you assign names to void values). Unfortunately this is indeed poorly-documented, but you can see it in [the source code of `Value::setName`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/Value_8cpp_source.html#l00175). It also makes sense when you consider how constants look in the textual representation of the IR.

What you can do instead is create a [global variable](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#global-variables) and mark it as constant - those can be named.